# Joins: Incorrect result when SUM() is used and only one record is displayed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

Please have a look at the below SQL Query

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*, 
Client.Name AS "Client Name", 
Provider.Name AS "Provider Name", 
Initial_Fees.*,
Portfolio.VAT,
Portfolio.Invest_Amount,
Portfolio.Cash_Value,
SUM(Ongoing_Fees.Fee)
FROM Client_Portfolio 
LEFT JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient 
LEFT JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.idPortfolio = Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio 
LEFT JOIN Provider ON Provider.idProvider = Portfolio.idProvider 
LEFT JOIN Initial_Fees ON Initial_Fees.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio 
LEFT JOIN Ongoing_Fees ON Ongoing_Fees.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
ORDER BY Client_Portfolio.idClient
```

This query generates incorrect results, but if I remove the "`SUM(Ongoing_Fees.Fee)`" part, then this generates the correct result.

`Ongoing_Fees` is a Table, and some `Portfolios` might have `Ongoing_Fees`, while others don't. I was trying to Sum the total Ongoing_Fees belong to each portfolio seperatly and get the result with the above query. But it went wrong.. It gave me the `Ongoing_Fees` sum of the entire table, and the entire above query returned just 1 row! How can I fix this?

Comment: Aggregate function without group by ? You may need a group by clause at the end.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Thanks for the reply. How can I apply it?

Comment: Add the following before the order by as `group by Client.idClient` and also make it a part of the selection.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: It didn't work, the SUM() now shows 2 results, but incorrectly calculated. And, I have more than 2 rows.

Comment: hmm could you create a fiddle with some data in http://sqlfiddle.com and expected result into the question. Doing group by with aggregate will sum of the record per group so if there are duplicate idclient then it will display one one row by summing up their data.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Seems like it should be `GROUP BY Portfolio.idPortfolio`.

Comment: Ah ok.. Yes it could be I just added the example as idclient, but yes if its idPortfolio which you want to get result then yes do group by that column.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty:  pls provide as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using  aggregate function `sum()` without `group by` so it will give you one single row.
If you want to get the result of sum per group then you must use group by clause at the end.

From the discussion you may need to add

`group by Portfolio.idPortfolio` before the order by clause.

This will give you sum value per  idPortfolio from the selection.

Check here more on it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html